# AJAX request fail in php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a two php page.

1. Which shows the calender when you select the month.
2. Other is the file which pops the calender into the 1st page.

I'm using XMLHttRequest to send the month value and get the days of that month.

**1st PHP Page**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMonth(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","showmonthCalender.php?month="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<form>
                        <select name="month" class="default" tabindex="2" onChange="showMonth(this.value)">
                                    <option value="01">JANUARY</option>
                                    <option value="02">FEBRUARY</option>
                                    <option value="03">MARCH</option>
                                    <option value="04">APRIL</option>
                                    <option value="05">MAY</option>
                                    <option value="06">JUNE</option>
                                    <option value="07">JULY</option>
                                    <option value="08">AUGUST</option>
                                    <option value="09">SEPTEMBER</option>
                                    <option value="10">OCTOBER</option>
                                    <option value="11">NOVEMBER</option>
                                    <option value="12">DECEMBER</option>
                        </select>
                        </form>

<div id="txtHint">display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2nd PHP File (showmonthCalender.php)**

```
<?php
$monthfetch = $_GET['month'];
$carry = "<div class='clear'></div>";
if ($monthfetch == '01' || $monthfetch == '03' || $monthfetch == '05' || $monthfetch == '07' || $monthfetch == '08' || $monthfetch == '10' || $monthfetch == '12')
    {
        for($i=01; $i<32; $i++)
        {
            $d = $i;
            $y = date('Y');
            $theDate = $y.'-'.$monthfetch.'-'.$d;
            $day = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthfetch, $d, $y));
            $carry = $carry . "<div class='dateHolder'>
                        <div class='date'>
                            <div class='valueHoliday'>
                                $d
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='day'>
                            <div class='valueHoliday'>
                                $day
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='clear'></div>";
        }
        echo "$carry";
    }
?>
```

For testing purpose i'm only selecting months which have 31 days. But when I select a month from the 1st php file, nothing gets displayed. I'm unable to solve the issue.

Help is needed.

Comment: I suggest using a library for AJAX calls (such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com)). It really simplifies things.

Comment: Already have a jquery library linked to the 1st page. But I've 3 more javascript running on that page. Does it effects on this?

Comment: As @JanDvorak suggest's I would use a library like jQuery to make these calls. However, i've just tested the two code examples you posted and they seem to work fine - I can pick a month from the drop down and it returns the days.

Comment: @user1731476 — But you aren't using it for this

Comment: I've 3 more javascript running on that page. does that effect?

Comment: @user1731476 jQuery is great at making ajax calls: `$.get(url).success(callback).error(logger)`

Comment: If there is an error in your other javascript code then it could affect the AJAX call

Comment: No there is no error, I've tested

Comment: There is no error in the code you've posted either - I can pick a Month from the drop down and it returns the dates of each day of the month

Comment: How many js can run on a page when I've only one jquery library liked to it?

Comment: There is no data displayed if you select November...

Comment: I'm selecting only 31 days month, like march, july, dec

Comment: @user1731476 A single page can have as much code as you like, but: 1) it shouldn't throw an exception, and 2) execution takes time.

Comment: actually the select box has an styling which is done by jquery. so does that effect the working. Because i just deleted that file and it works fine.

Comment: Also see [`$(...).load(url)`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which makes an AJAX call and stores the result into the selected element.

Comment: @user1731476 show us the "styling which is done by jquery".

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dropkick.css" type="text/css">
 <script src="../js/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
      $('.default').dropkick();
    });
  </script>`

Comment: `<form>
                     <select name="month" class="default" tabindex="2" style="width: 200px; height:40px;" onChange="showMonth(this.value)">
                  </select>
                        </form>`

Comment: well, I don't know dropkick enough to conclude it couldn't be the reason.

Comment: Oh and please don't use `onChange`. Add an event handler from javascript (separation of concerns, you may want multiple handlers etc.). Not saying this couldn't solve the issue as the plugin might trigger the `change` event but not run the `onChange` attribute.

Comment: @JanDvorak can u suggest me the code please.

Comment: With your current HTML, `$("select[name=month]").on("change", showMonth)` and modify the handler to use `$(this).val()` instead of its argument. Better to add an ID to the `select`, though, and use `$("#id").on(...`

Comment: `$("select[name=month]").on("change", showMonth)` where i need to add this. I'm a amature learner of AJAX. So need you to edit my code. please

Comment: Oh and have you seen the Chosen plugin? http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: You can attach a handler from anywhere (not related to AJAX) but you probably want to add it on page load => add it into a ready block: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: thanks that may solve the issue.